# Postgres in Azure Flask Web App

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, web-applications, flask

I've got Flask up and running as per this tutorial
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-flask-app/

I want Postgres to be my database system, but I'm in a Web App, so I can't just log into the VM and install it. What can I do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we don’t have permission to install PostgreSQL database on Azure Web APP server. You need install PostgreSQL on Azure VM.

For examples:

A. If you created a Windows Server VM, refer to the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-tutorial/ and connect your VM.

At the link page http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows, you can download a PostgreSQL Windows Installer file and run it on your VM to install it using default configuration step by step.

The PostgreSQL default port is 2345. Make sure the Windows Server Firewall  allow the port accessing and try to test the connection by using VM DNS NAME from your local host, and then you can continue to develop.

B. If you create a Linux VM such as Ubuntu，refer to the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-tutorial/ and connect your VM.

To install PostgreSQL, you can use Linux Package Management Tool.
Refer to the link:https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

RedHat/CentOS:
Refer to the link:http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation

You can use SQLAlchemy ORM Framework in Flask for PostgreSQL, please refer to http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/ and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/postgresql.html.

Comment: thanks for your comments, very useful. I could use a Linux VM, but what happens when I want to scale out?

Comment: as Peter said, we can create VM to host PostgreSQL, and use azure web app to host your application, we just need to scale our web app as this article said: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/, in addition, we can create PostgreSQL VM directory in new portal (http://portal.azure.com), please choose the right size as your data server.

Comment: Thanks for Jambor. There is a introduction article about VM & Cloud Service AutoScaling https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-auto-scaling/. I hope it can help you understand.